# MYSQL – how to remove characters from the middle of a string

Tags: mysql

How would I go about removing the middle characters from a string longer than 11 characters but keeping the first four and last four characters?

So for example `WOOLAHRA0427` would become `WOOL0427`.

I know I can use `length` to limit the selection to strings longer than 11, and am aware of `substr`, but that will rely on knowing how long my strings are (they vary) and will remove from the beginning, rather than leaving the beginning intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `left()`, `right()`, and `concat()`:

```
select concat(left(col, 4), right(col, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr`. This is intended just as an alternative way of what Gordon Already answered.

As this:

```
select concat( substr(yourField, 1, 4 ), substr(yourField, -4 ) )
```